# Http Post not posting

Tags: android, http, http-post

So I'm trying to send a post request to websites in order to search for specific things, like games on a gaming website.  The problem is that whenever I execute the post, it only seems to return the main website with the post value put into the search bar, but not the result page.  I would print out the whole log, but it's incredibly long, so I just took the part where it's placing my string, but it's still the main page.

```
public class Search extends Fragment {

/*Fragment Variables*/
private String[] results = new String[]{};
private EditText searchEdit;
private View view;

/*AsyncTask Variables*/
private Document doc;
private String urlString = "http://www.vogella.com";
private String title;
private String gamespotSearchId = "siteSearch";
private List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    searchEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    new BackGroundTask().execute();
    return view;
}
class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.gamespot.com");
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", "final fantasy"));
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // writing response to log
                readStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request

        return null;
    }

    private void readStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        BufferedReader buf = null;
        try{
            buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while((line = buf.readLine())!= null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(buf != null){
                try{
                    buf.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute", "just set the text view");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

Log

```
I/System.out( 7052):         </div>
I/System.out( 7052):       </div>
I/System.out( 7052):     </div>
I/System.out( 7052):   </section>
I/System.out( 7052):   <div class="container">
I/System.out( 7052):     <div class="masthead-container masthead-container--flex masthead-            container--buffer">
I/System.out( 7052):       <!-- Logo -->
I/System.out( 7052):               <h1 id="masthead-logo" class="masthead-logo">
I/System.out( 7052):           <a href=/ data-click-track-id=coreHeaderFrontDoor  class="logo-site">
I/System.out( 7052):             <span class="logo-site--short"></span>
I/System.out( 7052):             <span class="logo-site--full"></span>
I/System.out( 7052):           </a>
I/System.out( 7052):         </h1>
I/System.out( 7052):       
I/System.out( 7052):       <!-- Search -->
I/System.out( 7052):               <form action="/search/" method="get" id="siteSearch" class="masthead-search search">
I/System.out( 7052):           <fieldset>
I/System.out( 7052):             <i class="icon icon-search"></i>
I/System.out( 7052):             <input type="text" id="search-main" name="q"
I/System.out( 7052):                               placeholder="Search GameSpot"
I/System.out( 7052):                           autocomplete="off" class="search-input ready" data-search-index="game" value="final fantasy" />
I/System.out( 7052):           </fieldset>
I/System.out( 7052):         </form>
I/System.out( 7052):       
I/System.out( 7052):       <nav id="masthead-nav" role="navigation" class="masthead-nav">
I/System.out( 7052):         <ul class="nav-bar">
I/System.out( 7052):           <li class="nav-bar__item dropnav js-dropnav">
I/System.out( 7052):             <a href=/new-games/ data-click-track-id=coreHeaderNewGames >Games<i class="icon icon-caret-down"></i></a>
I/System.out( 7052):             <i class="icon icon-caret-down js-dropnav-toggle"></i>
I/System.out( 7052):             
I/System.out( 7052): <ul class="dropnav-menu dropdown-menu dropnav-menu--has-sidePanel dropnav-menu--has-sidePanel--right dropnav-menu--games arrow--top dropnav-menu--has-borderRadius js-dropnav-active">
I/System.out( 7052):   <li class="dropnav-menu__item dropnav-menu__active">
I/System.out( 7052):     <a href="/new-games/">New Games</a>
I/System.out( 7052):     <ul class="dropnav-submenu">
I/System.out( 7052):       <li class="dropnav-submenu__item dropnav-submenu__viewAll">
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Chrome [PostMan Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to do the same thing and I got the same result.

I doubt Gamespot wants people scraping their page like this, maybe they are filtering out by user-agent header or something similiar.

Looking at their HTML, I wouldn't want to try it anyway.

Comment: This is my first time doing anything thats HTTP related.  Is it common for websites to prevent scraping? And thanks for that tool it looks really cool.

Answer (score 0):

It's work to print PHP echo message by Java http post

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://192.195.68.83/Upload/index.php");

ArrayList<NameValuePair> arrayList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd", "1"));
arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", "This is comment"));

postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arrayList));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
String state = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
Log.i("chauster",state);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what how this is different from my code, although it's done using a few different things, it looks like my code should work the same way as this does?